# Keeping selected an option in select dropdown with jquery after refresh

Tags: jquery, html, select, refresh, selected

I have small script that reloads a select containing the nicknames of the users in a chatroom. When someone clicks the select, the javascript refreshes it, repopulating the option from a php page to add people that have logged in and removing those who logged out.
The script works properly on reloading the select, but I want it to avoid losing the precedent selected option if a user clicks the select another time to refresh the list, and the script doesn't keep the correct option. All the code works properly, except that part of the jquery.

The JS (the jquery library is of course also on the page):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#Users").focusin(function() {
      var UsersSelect = $('#Users').val();
      $("#Users").load("users.php");
      $('select[name="Users"]').val(UsersSelect);
    });
  });
</script>
```

The html/php webpage:

```
<div id="UserList" name="UserList">
<select name="Users" id="Users">
<?
$queryprep = "select name FROM users";
$query = $PDO->prepare($queryprep);
$query->execute();
while($rs = $query->fetch()) {
    echo "<option value=".$rs['name'].">".$rs['name']."</option>";
}
$query = null;
?>
</select>
</div>
```

The users.php page:

```
<select name="Users" id="Users">
<?
$queryprep = "select name FROM users";
$query = $PDO->prepare($queryprep);
$query->execute();
while($rs = $query->fetch()) {
    echo "<option value=".$rs['name'].">".$rs['name']."</option>";
}
$query = null;
?>
</select>
```

Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is asynchronous so you are trying to reset the value before the data will be populated. Once the options are replaced the select will lose the value again

Use the `complete callback` of `load()`

```
$("#Users").focusin(function() {
    var $select=$(this),  UsersSelect = $select.val();
    $select.load("users.php", function(){
       /* new html exists now s we can set value*/
       $select.val(UsersSelect);
    });
})
```

Comment: I replaced the code, but now the select is not reloaded at all.

Comment: Yes I did, and everything looked fine.

Comment: works fine here  http://jsfiddle.net/w4GuM/1/ Not so sure that triggering this on `focusin` is best idea though

Comment: It works with chrome, but with firefox seems to still reload the value. I did chose focusin in my original version because using onclick did trigger another reload when selecting the option.

Comment: i was testing it in firefox...what I meant was why do you need to wait until user focuses on select to make ajax call. Can take a bit of time on slow connection. WOn't be surprised either if IE has hiccups with this idea

Comment: I don't really need to have to wait the user to focus, I simply wanted to avoid a timeout reload because the list needs to be refreshed only when the user wants to scroll it and select another nickname on the list itself.

Comment: There is a way to keep the selected value not only in the list but in the selected box also?

Comment: if you are simply removig one name after user selects it....there are far easier ways that making ajax call and replacing them all. That can be done with a `change` handler

Comment: `change` almost did it, but it doesn't update the list when it's opened, only when a user changes option. I would like to have a list reload when a user clicks it, but avoiding the loss of selection both in the select "box" and in the scroll down.

Comment: but what are the differences? Do you really need to get new ones from server? Will be much faster if you only modify existing

Comment: Yes I do, when opened the list shows all the users in the same chatroom and allows to select the nickname of user who will receive a private message, and when other people enters, I'd like to have a list updated on the moment it drops down, so it will be more intuitive to use.