# Select box losing selected option when refreshed

Tags: php, jquery, select, refresh, selected

I'm trying to create a select box that refreshes its options when selected by the user, but I'm encountering a problem that I can't figure ho to solve.
Being still a beginner with jquery I've already asked an advice for the same program: [Keeping selected an option in select dropdown with jquery after refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20589466/keeping-selected-an-option-in-select-dropdown-with-jquery-after-refresh).

Following the suggestion now it works almost completely, but I'd like the dropdown to behave exactly as a non dynamic one, keeping the selected option when opened, except for having the options list also refreshed: now it “almost” keeps the value selected (it retains it in the dropdown) but resets to the first option when the element lose focus to others in the page and I don't know how to resolve the problem. I tried to pass a variable with ajax to the php page to have it selected on refresh, but it still resets when focus is change.

The JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#UsersDiv").focusin(function() {
        var UsersSelect = $('#UsersList').val();
        $.get( 
            "userlist.php",
            { UserSelect1: UsersSelect },
            function(data) {
            $('#UsersList').html(data);
            }
        );
    })
    $('#UsersList').val(UsersSelect);
});
```

The html page:

```
<div name="UsersDiv" id="UsersDiv">
<select name="UsersList" id="UsersList">
<option value="User1">User1</option>
<option value="User2">User2</option>
</select>
</div>
```

The php file (the “users” array is in place of the sql query, both work properly):

```
$UserSelect1 = $_GET['UserSelect1'];
$users=array( 'User1','User2','User3','User4','User5');

echo '<select name="UsersList" id="UsersList">';

foreach($users as $list):
echo '<option value="'.$list.'" ';
if ($UserSelect1 == $list) {
    echo 'selected=selected';
}
echo '>'.$list.'</option>';
endforeach;

echo '</select>';
```

Thanks to everyone for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#UsersDiv")
```

than you assigning this

```
 $select=$(this) // $select is $("#UsersDiv");
```

and than you are trying to get val from div

```
 UsersSelect = $select.val() // $select.val() is undefined
```

Comment: I've updated and tested the script, now it seems to still lose the var or simply to not set it properly after the refresh.

Comment: First of all $(document).ready(function(){ is function, which executing when your DOM is loaded, so $('#UsersList').val(UsersSelect); do nothing in fact. Try to debug your request - put some var_dump() in PHP and alert(data) in your $.get success function. It's hard to say what exactly is wrong, cause in my opinion this script now works correctly. I've check this code on my localhsot, and if on load page the value of select is User2, after ajax it stay selected.

Comment: It nearly works on Chrome (the select needs to be clicked twice to be refreshed), but still reset to null with FF, showing a white box when reloads and losing the selection if the focus change (eg, clicking another element on a page).